# Programmatic way to validate a Linux Login/password

Tags: linux, security, pam

I would to like to validate a username and password correspond to a valid unix account.

The current solution I have uses expect to wait for a password prompt and then supply the password and see if the login succeeds.

Is there a kernel API or a user space function that can validate a login / password.

I guess part of my confusion is I am not sure if this is a kernel space service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use pam. On debian/ubuntu you can:

```
apt-get install python-pam
```

Simple code in **python** [pamtest.py](http://www.google.com/codesearch#ac7IcfNzZOs/pub/mirrors/debian/pool/main/p/python-pam/python-pam_0.4.2-12.tar.gz%7C_MFVqE0lMAI/python-pam-0.4.2/examples/pamtest.py&q=%22Go%20away!%20(%25s)%22&type=cs):

See the `/usr/share/doc/python-pam/examples/pamtest.py` file. It's really short and does what you want.

To test it, run:

```
python /usr/share/doc/python-pam/examples/pamtest.py
```

There is also an example in **C** [pamexample.c](http://www.google.com/codesearch#ac7IcfNzZOs/pub/mirrors/debian/pool/main/p/python-pam/python-pam_0.4.2-12.tar.gz%7C_MFVqE0lMAI/python-pam-0.4.2/examples/pamexample.c&type=cs).

To test it:

```
gcc /usr/share/doc/python-pam/examples/pamexample.c -lpam -l pam_misc
./pam_misc theuser
```

Comment: The links in this answer seam to be dead..

Answer (score 3):

It's [strictly user-space](http://checkpasswd-pam.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 2):

to check if a user credentials are good you can try logging as him:

```
su - username
```

But reading about PAM may be a better route in the long term

Comment: To kick start your search, this is a page with a list of different PAM  modules... http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/pam/modules.html

Comment: this is nonprogrammatic; when done programatically, I hope you validate against bobby tables.